# SQL how to select two colums while using aggregate function for temp table

Tags: sql, count

Hi I a creating temp table with 2 columns and i want to fill the columns based on group by and aggregate function

```
insert into #temp (TagName,TagIdentifier)
select Tagname ,
    (case when charindex(':',TagClassDescription)> 0 
       then substring(TagClassDescription,1,(charindex(':',TagClassDescription)-1)) 
       end) as TagIdentifier 
from EXEC_REP_TransposedTagAttributes 
group by Tagname having count(tagname)>1 ;
```

but it gives the following error

---

**Column 'EXEC_REP_TransposedTagAttributes.TagClassDescription' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

I need both the values in my temp table and want to have `TagIdentifiers` value into my table based on the `count () >1`

Need help on this

Thanks

Comment: If you add `TagClassDescription` to the `group by` does it not give you what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the last line

group by Tagname having count(tagname)>1,TagClassDescription

Answer (score 0):

Use sub select, like the following:

insert into #temp (TagName,TagIdentifier) field1, field2
as (SELECT * 
    FROM TransposedTagAttributes 
    where tagname in 
   (SELECT tagname
    FROM EXEC_REP_TransposedTagAttributes
    group by Tagname having count(tagname)>1))

Comment: no of records expected to be in table is 11000+ but i am obtaining more than 20000+

Comment: this is beacasue the sub query is selecting the tagname so all the tags are repeated twice in the table resulting in double records

Comment: AI-350004 AI 
AI-350004 NULL